# Отлаживание WCF служб

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, wcf, веб-программирование

Подскажите, я запускаю в дебаггере одновременно 2 проекта: клиент и сервер.
Когда я попадаю через клиент в код сервера, то клиент через какое-то время вылетает с ошибкой.

Если продолжить дебаг, то в итоге пошлется еще 1 запрос и в итоге я в коде службы уже дебажу 2 запроса...
Подскажите, как поправить можно?

Comment: А зачем дебажить  сервер через клиента? Отладили серверную часть юнит-тестами, запустили, отлаживаем клиента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать увеличивать таймауты. Т.е. поставить `receiveTimeout` в `infinite`, но это может не помочь так как скорее всего вылетает из-за `operationTimeout` который через файл конфигурации насколько я помню нельзя поменять - только в коде.

А вообще правильно советуют - отлаживать сервер отдельно, напрямую вызывая методы. Хоть юнит-тестами, хоть отдельным консольным приложением.

Comment: Я в принципе придумал костыль. Я обромил вызов метода в клиенте в try/catch и в блоке catch просто ReadKey поставил и при ошибке теперь клиент "засыпает"